# Date format in oracle

Tags: oracle

Hai,

From the database i want to take only month from the whole date format.While taking i'm getting the month as 08 for August and 09 for september etc.But i need to get the month as 8 for August and 9 for september etc.

How can i do it? Can any one help me?

Answer (score 5):

```
  select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'mm')) from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

This query returns 09:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MM') from dual
```

This query returns 9:

```
select ltrim(to_char(sysdate, 'MM'),'0') from dual
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, does it with just one function call:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'FMMM') from dual;
```

See [Format Model Modifiers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) for details of the 'FM' syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to know about the FM operator is that it basically functions as a 'toggle'.  Think about the FM element as a prefix that acts on the **entirety** of the datetime element.

So in this case, where you only need the month, FMMM says, essentially, 'bring back MM (month between 1 and 12) but leave off leading zeros.'

If, for instance, you used:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'FMMMDD') from dual;
```

that would be interpreted as 'bring back MMDD (month between 1 and 12, day between 1 and 31) but leave off leading zeros **from both the month and the day.**

If your date was August 8th, for instance,

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'MMMDD') from dual;
```

would return

```
0808
```

adding the FM operator

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'FMMMDD') from dual;
```

would return

```
88
```

note how the FM operates on the entirety of the datetime element.